# Ada: rounding divided integers

Tags: ada

I'm having much trouble with operation which seems to be very simple. I'm willing to round quotient. I know that `I : Integer := A/B`, (where A and B are Integers) return floor. But I want to get ceiling. I've been trying to play with `'Ceiling` `'Round` `'Rounding` but none of them seems to work (most of the times it didn't even compile). I'm hoping for a quick answer, with a elegant (is it possible to write it without dozen type conversions) solution ;D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally I’d say

```
I : Integer := (A + (B - 1)) / B;
```

(typically come across when trying to work out how many storage units you need to accommodate a certain number of bits).

Comment: And that's what I'm talking about when I mentioned elegant solution ;D Thanks very much